# Confusing multi threading example

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;

   ThreadDemo( String name) {
      threadName = name;
      System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
      try {
         for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
            // Let the thread sleep for a while.
            Thread.sleep(50);
         }
      }catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   public void start () {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null) {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
}

public class TestThread {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread-1");
      T1.start();

      ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread-2");
      T2.start();
   }   
}
```

This code sample is from tutorials point multi threading tutorial. Is the start() method defined in the class ThreadDemo really necessary? Wont the code be cleaner, if that is removed? Or is there something I am not understanding here?

Comment: This is *dreadful* code. I'd recommend you find another resource from which to learn.

Comment: You are correct: the `start` method (which should be tagged `@Override`) serves no purpose here, along with both of the member variables: a `Thread` doesn't need a `Thread` inside it, and it already allows you to set a name.

Comment: You should not overrive `run()` of a Thread and you definitely shouldn't override `start()` if you have any idea what you are doing.  In this case you can replace `extends Thread` with `implements Runnable`

Comment: One of the terrible things about the class is that it both extends `Thread` AND has a `Thread` as a field.  How can we not get confused about which thread is which?  Especially with such an uninformative name for the field.  Ditch this tutorial NOW.

Comment: Read Oracle's tutorials. You'll know it's not written by someone who has delusions of his skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making this an answer because I feel we both need to *explain* **what's so wrong the example** (*not only does it show a bad example of MultiThreading, it also exposes a lack of understanding of Object-Oriented Programming*) AND we need to **put you back on the right learning path**. My answer will of course echo the other comments you got.

### The first very, very wrong thing is this:

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   [...Stuff...]
}
```

A ThreadDemo instance *is* a Thread instance (remember ThreadDemo  extends Thread). If you embed a Thread object in it, then that makes two distinct Thread instances. This is :

- Wasteful (two instances are not needed, only one Thread instance is required
- **Confusing** (which instance really 'counts'? which one is running?)
- Going to end in an **error due to side-effects**. Indeed invoking `start()`, `stop()` or anything on the wrapper ThreadDemo instance will probably not affect the wrapped Thread instance object in the correct way, if at all.

Multithreading can be disorienting at times, you don't need any of this messing with your head.

### Remove that

...and the whole example can be rejected, as there are barely 3 lines worth anything, and they are not related to the Multithreading processes.

---

### Here's a path to learning about this:

1. Block the website where you found this code from your browser, because it is evil and you'll get tainted by it.
2. Read up on the difference between [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) because the source Author failed to grasp it. Basically your class only needs to be Runnable here.
3. Use the official [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), they are really good. don't bother reading about synchronization stuff yet, because for now your code is [embarrasingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).
4. Once you get that, use an [Executor Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) everwhere instead of instancing `Thread`s and `start`ing them. This is where you leverage Java's powerful built-in libraries.
5. When you are confident about all the above, make your Threads work together on a more complex `run()` method - you'll need [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) for that.
6. Pull your hair
7. Come back to S:O for advice :D

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

We need to explicitly create an object of class Thread when we are performing multhreading by implementing Runnable interface. In the case of implementing Runnable interface, we gotta create Thread object. Having said that, since here the ThreadDemo class already extends Thread, we need to do it in the start method, while we must have done it while implementing Runnable.